# Fill area chart based on values in three.js

Tags: three.js

I created an area chart with three.js. Each datapoint creates two triangles, one from bottom to height of the value to the next value height, one to fill the gap. Pretty similiar to the work of gmarland at http://gmarland.github.io/mercer/ (which I found after creating it when researching for a solution for this question, hard luck...).

Not knowing of any option to fill the area with a gradient as a whole, I filled the single triangles with vertexColors. Works, but obviously low values have the same color-gradient as higher ones just at another scale. Creating a nice effect but not visualizing the actual data. So here is the challenge where I can't think of a nice solution yet:

I would like to fill the area with a gradient that reflects the values. I.e. from 0 (yellow) to 100 (blue) and if a value is in between it stops somewhere at orange.
If I'd apply that logic using vertexColors for my triangles, the single triangles would get visible, as they'd have different colors at different heights, so that's not an option.

Any chance to fill the whole mesh (so, area of the chart) with a gradient?

Example of a 2D chart with that "effect": http://users.infragistics.com/2013.2/Ignite/Chart-Gradient.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the sounds of this i think you want to use a texture. You can generate several  `THREE.DataTexture` all of witdh 1 and height 100. Several to make things simple with filtering.  Fill them up with your values and then map them to your triangles using some logic.

Either scaled by the max height of these graphs, or the entire graph (looks like the red represent the peak of the curve, not the ceiling of the graph).

This is very similar to what you are doing with vertex colors, but instead of vertex colors, you need to generate UVs. U can always be 0 for every vertex, V is just the height of the vertex, normalized.

Comment: Thanks! I couldn't complete it yet, but it's definetely the right direction and I'll get it done soon. Cheers!